# What are the off-airfield rules for private helicopters in New Zealand?

Tags: landing, helicopter, new-zealand

I'm a Switzerland-based private helicopter pilot planning to spend some time in NZ. I'm wondering what are the rules there regarding off-airfield landing. Is it possible at all? Is the land owner approval required? Are their any altitude limitations like in Switzerland? What are the typical practices there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the relevant rules around helicopter landings are covered by [CAA Part 91](https://www.caa.govt.nz/rules/Rule_Consolidations/Part_091_Consolidation.pdf) section **91.127 Use of aerodromes**.

You are permitted to land a helicopter off-airfield. Land owner approval is required (except in the case of emergency), just like any other use of land.